pyinstaller --onefile FASER_MAIN.py - Exe file can't find other .py files when run
Any help greatly appreciated. I am trying to use pyinstaller to create a .exe file. Details below:
File Structure:
C:\Faser (contains all .py files)

C:\Faser\IO_Files (contains user editable files (excel) used by the program).

C:\Faser\Documentation (contains user docs)

C:\Faser_externals (security data user editable, read by the program)

.py Files
FASER_API_io

FASER_globals

FASER_InputExcelTo360

FASER_LOGIN_general

FASER_Login_special

FASER_SourceExceltoInputExcel

FASER_MAIN.py

imports to include other files
import FASER_LOGIN_general
import FASER_LOGIN_special

import FASER_InputExcelTo360

import FASER_SourceExcelToInputExcel

import FASER_globals

import FASER_API_io

Commands run (two different methods to try and resolve the issue):
pyinstaller FASER_MAIN.py

pyinstaller --onefile FASER_MAIN.py

When I click on the button to run FASER_SourceExceltoInputExcel, the following error is reported:
pyinstaller python: can't open file 'C:\FASER\FASER_SourceExcelToInputExcel.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Also, the required extra folders (and their files) are not there:
C:\Faser\IO_Files (contains user editable files (excel) used by the program).

C:\Faser\Documentation (contains user docs)

C:\Faser_externals (security data user editable, read by the program)

I've edited FASER_MAIN.spec to try and add the files to collect, but every time I run pyinstaller, it seems to clear out the entries.
